# Registering clicks on a button

Tags: javascript

I have created a button in JavaScript with the following details:

```
<td id='2,A,B,C' onclick='enterKey(this.id)'>2</td>
```

When the JS is passed through the function an array is created:

```
string = string.split(',')
```

meaning string[0] is 2, string[1] is A and henceforth....

The question I wanted to ask is how do I get JS to register multiple presses on the button.

So if the user presses the  twice - they get A instead of 2. If they press it three times - they get B. But if they press is 5 times - it reverts back to 2.

Any advice on how I can achieve this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think `,` is a valid character for IDs. You should use a `data-` attribute instead. Regarding your question: Do you basically want to alternate event handlers per click, or do you want execute a handler based on how often a user clicked? Like in the first case, the first click executes handler A, the second click handler B, and so forth. In the second case, two rapid clicks would trigger handler B but not handler A.

Comment: Well the text is entered into a text field and the id is passed into function enterKey to be added to the text field.

Comment: i.e. `document.getElementById('searchStr').value+=string;` - I would like for the key in particular to simulate a mobile keypad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have an invalid ID:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

However, assuming you either revise it to use, say, a period or something else, you can track it but just assigning the "click count" to an attribute on the td. For instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function incCounter(e){
    var count = e.getAttribute('data-clicks') || 0,
        id = e.getAttribute('data-clickid').split(',');

    e.innerHTML = id[++count % id.length];
    e.setAttribute('data-clicks', count);
  }
</script>

<td data-clickid="2,a,b,c" onclick="incCounter(this);"></td>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/1/)

Then read the data attribute to determine which element of the "ID array" you need to reference.

Comment: You need to make this loop around once it hits the array length but otherwise this is definitely the correct solution. Avoid global variables when possible.

Comment: @David: Agreed, not fool-proof but this is the route I would take it. Keep it element-based and you'll be able to retrieve the associated ID based on the value (or absence) of data-clicks

Comment: According to your quote, the id "must begin with a letter".  Those ids that start with `2` are also invalid.  As this is clearly data, and not an identifier, I'd stick that into a `data-*` attribute as well.

Comment: @gilly3: Indeed, can you tell it's the end of the day? ;-) Edited it to use two data attributes, which should be better.

Comment: Can you please explain this line of code to me `var count = e.getAttribute('data-clicks') || 0,`

Comment: `var count = e.getAttribute('data-clicks') || 0` attempts to get the attribute `data-clicks` from the td and if it doesn't exist, set it to 0.

Comment: @methuselah: Indeed, William nailed it. "If data-clicks has a value, use that. If it's unassigned, default to the value of 0". Basically, it assigned the first non-null value.

Comment: @BradChristie - here is the code I'm using at the moment. Really struggling to apply what you've provided there as I have yet to be introduced to those features of JavaScript yet. As you can see the count is still being carried over - http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/7/

Comment: @methuselah: you're using a hybrid of my solution and another user's. Go back to [my original](http://jsfiddle.net/JNCCW/1/) and build from there, where the meta-data is element-specific and not a global count variable.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to declare a global variable outside of the method definition, and increment it on each press.

```
var count = 0;

function enterKey() {
    //Split and whatnot here
    var myValue = string[count];
    count++;
    if(count == 5) { 
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I have multiple tds i.e. `<td id='2,A,B,C' onclick='enterKey(this.id)'>2</td><td id='3,D,E,F' onclick='enterKey(this.id)'>3</td>` - it seems to still carry on the count from before. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

You would attach it dynamically somehow. So, for example, if you wanted to do this to all `<td>` elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var i, element;

for(i = 0; element = elements[i]; i++) {
    (function(element) {
        var data = element.getAttribute('data').split(',');
        var numClicks = 0;
        element.onclick = function() {
            enterKey(data[numClicks++ % data.length]);
        };
    })(element);
}
```

Note that I used `element.getAttribute('data')` instead of `element.id`; @FelixKling is correct, that's an invalid ID.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var count = 0;

function enterKey( string ) {
    string = string.split( "," );
    return string[(count++) % string.length];
}
```

Comment: This works great but when I click the button 5 times then it returns undefined instead of returning to the first element in the array. Could you please explain to me what `count %= string.length;` does?

Comment: Sorry, I updated it, should work now. The % operator returns the remainder when one value is divided by another. So, if the string length is 4 and count is 4, 4/4 = 1R0, and 0 will be returned (giving the begining index of the array).

Comment: What about if I have multiple tds i.e. `<td id='2,A,B,C' onclick='enterKey(this.id)'>2</td><td id='3,D,E,F' onclick='enterKey(this.id)'>3</td>` - when I click on3 then it seems to still carry on the count from before

Comment: That is because you are calling the same `enterKey` function from both tds. `enterKey` is using the global variable count to keep track. You would have to have a slightly different setup to have a different count for each td. Brad Christie has an example of how to do this.

Comment: I'm having a look at it now but it seems daunting as I am pretty new to JS!

Comment: Oh sorry, I combined some steps into one in the return statement. Basically this splits the string by a comma, then returns the element at index count. Except count is incremented (`count++`) and to make sure it is in the bounds of the array, modulus it by the length of the array.